# Buttons in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

This is the part of my code without the actual main class as that works fine. I am trying to write a program that if you press yes (item3) it says "Do you know the title of the book?", but if you press no (item4) it asks "Would you like to return a book". So far no matter which button I press it returns "Do you know the title of the book?". I know that it is because I changed isClicked to true here: 'private boolean isClicked = true;' but I don't have any idea how to change it so that it does what I want.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Welcome extends JFrame {
    private JLabel title1, title2; 
    private JButton item3, item4;

    public Welcome(){
        super("Welcome to Andrew's Library");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setBackground(Color.RED);   

        boolean isClicked = false;
        title1 = new JLabel("Welcome to Andrew's Library!!!");
        title2 = new JLabel("Would you like to check out a book?");
        item3 = new JButton("YES");
        item4 = new JButton("NO");

        add(title1);
        add(title2);
        add(item3);
        add(item4);

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();

        item3.addActionListener(handler);
        item4.addActionListener(handler);
    }

    private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
        private boolean isClicked = true;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

            if(isClicked){
                title1.setText("Do you know the title of the book?");
                title2.setText(null);       
            } else {
                title1.setText(null);
                title2.setText(null);   
                item3.setVisible(false);
                item4.setText("Do you want to return a book?");
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: `((item3) labelReference)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Do you know what to use instead?

Comment: Depends entirely what you intend, which is not at all obvious.  The syntax you used is a "cast", and the thing inside the inner parens should be a class name (a type) not a variable name.  Explain what you hoped to achieve with that statement.

Comment: You are register addMouseListener to a button and then when actionPerformed you are downcasting to a JLabel and then casting to a Type that seems not to be a Type like `item3` that is a variable

Comment: Ok originally it was  'labelReference.screen2();' but then the "screen2" in that line was showing an error saying to "add cast to 'labelReference'" so that is what I did

Comment: OK, you should understand by now via the comments that you shouldn't be using a MouseLisstener on JButtons, that you should be using an ActionListener instead. Have you made these changes yet? And you should understand that since you're adding the listener to JButtons you shouldn't try casting the source as a JLabel.

Comment: `item3` is `JButton`, but your trying to cast it through `JLabel`, these are incompatible to start with.  `JButton` also does not have a `screen2` method so even if did cast it to a `JButton`, it would still fail to compile...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What is "isClicked"? Your event listener should check the event, getting the source to see which button was clicked. Alternatively, create two event handlers: one for each button.

Comment: You need to learn how to have multiple listeners. isClicked is meaningless; your listener will only be called when there is a click. The problem is _who gets the message_. I'm voting to close the question, until the OP's source code is closer to a correct version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try this? Take the ActionEvent parameter and see if the source equals the JButton.

```
private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
  private boolean isClicked = true;
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    if(isClicked){
        title1.setText("Do you know the title of the book?");
        /** TODO uncomment here
        if(item3.equals(event.getSource())
          System.out.println("item3 pressed");
        else
          System.out.println("item4 pressed");
        //*/
    } else {...
```